# Ошибка в HealthKit при переходе на swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

При переходе на swift 3 вылезла ошибка, не могу разобраться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените в параметрах функции **NSError** на **Error**

```
func saveWorkoutForHealth(_ startDate: Date , endDate: Date , kiloCalories:Double,
                              completion: ((Bool, Error?)-> Void)!) {
```